# How to filter rows based on the value in two columns and a different value in a third

Tags: python, pandas

The following code generates a dataframe to illustrate my question

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1152, '1', '10'], [1154, '1', '4'],
       [1152, '1', '10'],  [1155, '2', '10'], 
       [1152, '1', '4'],  [1155, '2', '10']]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['Cow', 'Lact', 'Procedure'])
```

This generates the following

```
    Cow   Lact  Procedure
0   1152    1   10
1   1154    1   4
2   1152    1   10
3   1155    2   10
4   1152    1   4
5   1155    2   10
```

I want to identify the rows where Cow and Lact are the same but procedure is different. The output I am looking for is

```
    Cow   Lact  Procedure
0   1152    1   10
1   1152    1   10
2   1152    1   4
```

I figure it will require a groupby and filter function but not sure how to put it together.
Thanks

Comment: Why you have `1152    1   10` two times in the result? Why `1154    1   4` and others are filtered out?

Comment: *but procedure is different* - are you sure about your final output? it contains **same** procedure `10`

Comment: Yes I am looking for cows that have the same lactation number but different calving date recorded in the database.  For the example it was simpler to use a numeric variable called procedure.  Mozways code does exactly what I need.  Thanks for your inquiry and Thanks Mozay for the code. John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby.transform('nunique')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df.groupby(['Cow', 'Lact'])['Procedure'].transform('nunique').gt(1)]
```

Output:

```
    Cow Lact Procedure
0  1152    1        10
2  1152    1        10
4  1152    1         4
```